# SharePoint 2013 Search - Open PDF in new browser

Tags: search, jquery, ie8

I have some jquery(as suggested by someone on StackExchange) to open PDFs in a new browser window from the out of the box search restuls web part.

The code works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE8. Can anyone help me identify why?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr("onclick");
        $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr("onmousedown");
        $("a[href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");       
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I've used that works for me in IE8.  It works best in IE8 with jQuery version 1.8.2 in my case.

```
$(".srch-Title3 a").click(function() {
    href = $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase();
    if (href.indexOf(".pdf") !== -1) { 
        window.open(href, "_blank"); 
        return false; 
    }
});
```